# How to set C/C++ compiler options for best optimizations for the CPU in use?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-optimization, compiler-options

To build binaries with the best optimizations for a specific CPU, how to set C/C++ compiler options? For example, try to utilize CPU features like MMX/3DNow!/SSE/SSE2/SSE3 when the feature is available.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "features of the CPU in use?". Its difficult to understand exactly what you mean by this imo

Comment: the best method is to use profile-guided optimization. Just stick to a single compiler and enable PGO instead

Comment: Also, in gcc/clang, you can set `-march=<arch>` to the target chipset (use `native` for the local CPU).

Comment: @Weston For example, MMX,3DNow!,SSE,SSE2,SSE3, ..., use them when possible

Comment: @Frank no automatic way?

Comment: @phuclv no automatic way?

Comment: This is the sort of thing where if you asked five programmers what the best combination of compiler options were, you'd get 8 or ten different answers.

Comment: Like Frank said, the automatic way is `-march=native`.

Comment: IIRC, this is _one_ goal Clang tries to reach. Did you look up the documentation on `-march=native`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GCC and Clang support [`-march=native`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html) to select the CPU to generate code for from the processor type the compiler is executing on and `-mtune=native` to optimize code for it. Note that these switches are listed in specific architecture sections, such as the X86 or ARM architectures, so they might not be available for all architectures that the compiler supports.

Use `-march=native` if you want to generate code that does not need to execute on other processor models. `-march=native` implies `mtune=native`.

Use `-mtune=native` without `-march=native` if you want to generate code tuned for the current processor but that can still execute on the processor models it would be able to otherwise.